# Input Two string per line within blank space possible

Tags: c

What I need to do is to put the first **n** of second string input behind first string input .And every string may have blank space which I donot know how to set formatted input.
I try to do it like this.BUT wrong output.

```
void fun(char *s1, char *s2, int n){
    int l = strlen(s1);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    s1[l+i]=s2[i];}
}
int main(){ 
    char s1[10];char s2[10]; int n;
    scanf("%s\n",s1);
    scanf("%[^\n]",s2);
    scanf("%d",&n);
    fun(s1,s2,n);
    printf("%s",s1);
  return 0;
}
```

The output example:

```
hello
my bro
3
hellomy @
```

Comment: You need to manage the terminating `'\0'` properly for `s1` in `fun()` function. Also think about possible buffer overflows!

Comment: Use `fgets` instead of `scanf`

Comment: What if the second string has less characters than the specified number? Are you trying to implement `strncat`?  What do you mean with "wrong output"? Please [edit] your question and show both the output you actually get and what you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

The string handling functions in the C standard library is quite error prone so it's sometimes best to roll you own. Below is a solution which uses safe functions for reading a line of text and appending two strings.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void ReadLine(char result[], int resultLen)
{
    int ch, i;

    assert(resultLen > 0);
    i = 0;
    ch = getchar();
    while ((ch != '\n') && (ch != EOF)) {
        if (i < resultLen - 1) {
            result[i] = ch;
            i++;
        }
        ch = getchar();
    }
    result[i] = '\0';
}


void Append(const char extra[], char dest[], int destLen)
{
    int i, j;

    i = 0;
    j = strlen(dest);
    while ((extra[i] != '\0') && (j + i < destLen - 1)) {
        dest[j + i] = extra[i];
        i++;
    }
    dest[j + i] = '\0';
}


int main(void)
{
    char s1[10], s2[10];
    int count, n;

    ReadLine(s1, sizeof s1);
    ReadLine(s2, sizeof s2);
    count = scanf("%d", &n);
    if ((count == 1) && (n >= 0)) {
        Append(" ", s1, sizeof s1);
        if (n < (int) sizeof s2) {
            s2[n] = '\0';
        }
        Append(s2, s1, sizeof s1);
        puts(s1);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Non-negative integer expected\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example add only 3 first chars from `s2` ('m',  'y' and 'space') - this looks ok.

In `void fun()` you inserting part `s2` on the end of `s1` additionally overwriting '/0'.
The output should looks:

`"hellomy "`,  but you don't insert a null termination. So we see a:

`"hellomy @"`, this happend because  :`s1[9]` was '/0'

So in the worst case your edited `s1` string could be without null termination. So function `printf` will prints characters until it finds any '/0' after start reading memory. so program could generate access violation error...
Please consider protect string from exceed their dimension and proper null terminating...

Answer (score 0):

There are two fundamental problems here.  (Don't worry, they're problems with the C language, not with you or your program.)

1. There is no good, easy way in `scanf` to read a string that might contain whitespace.  (There's a way, which you tried, but it's confusing and has problems.)
2. A program that calls `scanf` to read some input cannot reasonably call `fgets` or `getchar` to read other input.  (Again, there are ways to make this work, but they're confusing and buggy and more trouble than they're worth.)

If you want to read a string that might contain whitespace, the only reasonable way to do it is to call `fgets`.  But if your program calls `fgets` to read some stuff, it cannot easily call `scanf` to read other stuff.  (In particular, the first time you use `scanf("%d", &n)` to read an integer, followed by `fgets` to read a line, you'e going to be back here on Stack Overflow asking why `fgets` mysteriously read a blank line.)

So what can you do?  Use `fgets` to read everything.  If you need a number, use `fgets` to read it as a string, then convert it to a number with `atoi` or `strtol`.

See also [What can I use for input conversion instead of scanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537) .